# how to get utilization rates of gpu? (nvml)

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvml

I need gpu information for my cuda project test.

I am using nvml library, and I successfully get temperature information.
But, nvml reports ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED in nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates().

So now, how to get utilization rates of gpu?
Clearly, there will be a way like NVIDIA GeForce Experience.

thanks,

p.s. oops! I am insufficient reputation...
If you want to see NVIDIA GeForce Experience example image, [click this link](http://locofield.com/Download/1.JPG).

Comment: Can't you use NVVP or NVPROF to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your graphics card, the GTX Titan (based on your image) simply does not support volatile GPU utilization?
I think this functionality is only supported on Quadro and Tesla cards.

Additionally, can you show how you use nvml in your code?

Comment: I am using GTX TITAN.
You're right. NVML is only supported on Quadro and Tesla.
But, I solve this problem using the nvapi-334.

Comment: It is very easy.
Please refer to this link:
http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

To see your GPU utilization in linux for nvidia cards use:

```
nvidia-smi
```

use -l to refresh for eg

```
nvidia-smi -l 1
```

this will refresh for every 1 second.